# Keyboard navigation on nested list using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I have a `ul` list as follows. I am new to JS and trying to do a keyboard navigation, just the arrow keys using only javascript.

```
<ul id= nav>
 <li class =subnav id =sub1> Companies
  <ul id = hidden>
   <li> item 1 </li>
   <li> item 2 </li>
   <li> item 3 </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class =subnav id =sub2> LINKS
  <ul id = hidden>
   <li> item 4 </li>
   <li> item 5 </li>
   <li> item 6 </li>
  </ul>
 </li>  
</ul>
```

my JS:

```
ul = document.getElementById("nav");
li = ul.getElementsByClassName("subnav");
ul2 = document.getElementById("hidden");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");


function keyPress(e)
{
   var e = e||window.event;
   e =e.which||e.keyCode;

   for( var i=0; i<li.length; i++)
   {
      var  f = li[i].childNodes[0]; 
      if(li[i].children.length > 0)
      {
         for(var j=0; j<li2.length; j++)
         {
            var x = li2[j].childNodes[0];
         }
      }
      else
      {
         alert("no child nodes");
      }  
   }
}
```

I am trying to set focus on the first item and then moving to each nodes using keys.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: You can do this using aria roles and tabIndex... Here is an example. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700327.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using jwerty, awesome keyboard events library.

I used jQuery and jWerty plugin.

Here is a quick JSFiddle: (Click the preview window and start hitting the down key)

http://jsfiddle.net/8QZrV/

As a basic idea, you should create an object with all the elements and then iterate through them, my basic example was like this:

```
    var i = 0;
    j = jQuery('.navigator li').length;
```

And then you hook it up in jwerty, I guess you want to make some actions there, so I guess you should also .focus() the current element.

Enjoy!